# Get different list of records whenever VF Page is refreshed

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to get different records from a query whenever the page is refreshed/reloaded...
For example, I have a query which returns the list of 10 accounts. Whenever I refresh the page I need to display another 10 account records on the VF Page. Can someone help me how to do this...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Do you want to display records randomly on each page load?

Comment: Yes, that's my requirement...

Comment: Then I would suggest to use the OFFSET parameter and randomly generate a value between 0 to (2000 or max number of records present). Then use this value in the query.